# The derivation of the quantum information no-hiding theorem, question 2

Tags: information-theory

I am reading [Samuel L. Braunstein, Arun K. Pati, Quantum information cannot be completely hidden in correlations: implications for the black-hole information paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0603046). The paper purportedly proves quantum information cannot be completely hidden in the ancilla. I am puzzling over the derivation in Section Perfect hiding processes. A closely related question is [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23745/2067).

Does Equation $(3)$ of the paper
$$\alpha^*\beta\langle A_l(\psi)|A_k(\psi_\perp)\rangle+\beta^*\alpha\langle A_l(\psi_\perp)|A_k(\psi)\rangle=0 \tag3$$
come from the following requirements?
$$\big\langle A_l(\alpha|\psi\rangle+\beta|\psi_\perp\rangle)\big| A_k(\alpha|\psi\rangle+\beta|\psi_\perp\rangle)\big\rangle=0, \tag{3.1}$$
$$\big\langle A_l(|\psi\rangle)\big| A_k(|\psi\rangle)\big\rangle=\big\langle A_l(|\psi_\perp\rangle)\big| A_k(|\psi_\perp\rangle)\big\rangle=0. \tag{3.2}$$
If so, what is the rigorous rationale for Equations $(3.1), (3.2)$?

Comment: are you asking whether (3) comes from (3.1) and (3.2), or are you asking where (3.1) and (3.2) come from? In the latter case, you should probably write in the post what $A_k$ represent, and something about the general context, to make the post self-contained

Comment: @glS: I am asking both questions. I edited my question slightly. The equation quoted is defined in the cited paper the link of which is explicitly provided.

Comment: ideally, questions should be as self-contained as possible. I'm still not sure what $A_k$ represent here? Are these the Kraus operators for some channel? If so, which channel?

Comment: @glS: However, this question is specifically directed at a specific paper. If I clarify one symbol, I will have to do it for all and the equation. These are all defined in the paper. Is your question regarding the Kraus operator arisen after having read the paper?